# On the relation between the supports of $\sum_\alpha c_\alpha D^\alpha \varphi$ and $\varphi$ in semispaces, $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Let $p = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha D^\alpha \in \mathbb{R}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $\mathscr{L} = p(D) = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha D^\alpha \newcommand{\L}{\mathscr{L}} \DeclareMathOperator{\diff}{Diff}, \DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}$ a linear partial differential operator.

I'm trying to understand the following result,

> Let $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If $\L \varphi = 0$ in an open semispace $H$, then $\varphi = 0$ in $H$.

The reference I am reading proves it first for $H_0 = \{x_1 > 0\}$. This I have understood. The claim then is that the general result follows by composing $\varphi$ with translations and rotations, which seems rather straight forward but I'm having a hard time formalizing it.

If $\L \varphi  = 0$ in $H$, we want to see that $\varphi = 0$ in $H$. Taking $\psi \in \diff(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as a rotation composed with a translation this is equivalent to showing that $\varphi \psi$ vanishes on $H_0$, and so it suffices to show that $\L (\varphi \psi)$ vanishes on $H_0$.

Rephrasing the original hypothesis, we know that $(\L\varphi) \circ \psi = 0$ on $H_0$, and so I would like to show that if $(\L \varphi) \circ \psi$ vanishes, then so does $\L (\varphi\psi)$. In other terms, is the inclusion

$$
\supp \L (\varphi\psi) \subset \sup (\L\varphi) \circ \psi
$$

true, and if so, how could one go about showing this?

Comment: Well, you should probably use the chain rule to derive $\widetilde{\mathscr{L}}(\varphi \circ \psi) = \mathscr{L}(\varphi)\circ \psi$ for a differential operator $\widetilde{\mathscr{L}}$ which is of a similar form as $\mathscr{L}$ and independent of the choice of $\varphi$.

Comment: That I have tried, but I couldn't manage to write it properly. I am almost sure that it suffices to prove the result for $\mathscr{L} = D^\alpha$ but I don't see a clear way of doing induction on $|\alpha|$, and expanding the expression via the chain rule more than once becomes rather cumbersome. If true, there must be a compact way of writing it which I ignore. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: Think about how a a partial derivative $\partial_i$ transforms under conjugation with a linear map (and under conjugation with a translation).

Comment: @PeterWildemann the translation case is straight forward, hence we could restrict ourselves to affine transformations (and by the aforementioned, to linear ones). I see that $D(\varphi T) = \nabla \varphi \cdot T$ for linear $T$, but computing this for arbitrary multiindices is giving me a hard time. Any further hints?

Comment: Think about $T D^{\alpha} T^{-1} = T D_1^{\alpha_1} T^{-1} \, T D_2^{\alpha_2} T^{-1} \cdots T D_n^{\alpha_n} T^{-1}$. And apply the transformation rule to every factor individually.